# Ruby function call: foo "bar" do

Tags: ruby

I'm (very) new to ruby. I found an interesting way to call a function, but I can't figure out how it really works.

```
def foo (arg1)
  puts arg1
end

foo "bar" do
  "hello"
  puts "world"
  thisStuff
end
```

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here? There is no function called "thisStuff", however the code compiles without a problem and the console result is "bar".

Comment: The `do` ... `end` is a *block*, essentially an anonymous function, passed to `foo`. It can be executed within the `foo` function using `yield`, but `yield` is never called so the block never executes.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly what I was looking for. Could you make your comment an official answer, so I could set it as a solution and close this question?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Ruby doesn't have functions. There are at least three different things in the code snippet you posted that one might conceivably call a "function", although none of them are called that way in Ruby. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: In the tutorials I've been using I learned, that ruby has both function and methods. My question was about the `foo` function, where you call it with a parameter, and then use do ... end block. 
Also, this question has already been answered. The usage of anonymous _function_ by using `yield` is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do` ... `end` is a *block*, essentially an anonymous function, passed to `foo`. It can be executed within the `foo` function using `yield`, but `yield` is never called so the block never executes.

You may also see these blocks declared using a `{}` syntax, which means the same as `do` ... `end`. They're mostly used in functional programming functions like `map` or `select`.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby block is a code you put around `do` - `end` keywords!

Blocks has **yield** keyword to execute some code. Take a look at this (source: http://mixandgo.com/blog/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes):

[image]

in your case your block `foo` didn't have a `yield` and hence when called it just executed the part in the block.Try adding a **yield** and you will get the exception as expected.

Checkout the above link to further explore blocks as they are one of Ruby powerful tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot (especially for a link), but OrangeFlash81 was first to answer my question. Therefore, I gave him the "answer" status, even though this one has more meat :).